# Add Pin It Pinterest Button to Videos on Website

Tags: html, vimeo, pinterest

How would I add a Pin it button to an embedded video on my website? I am able to add the Pin it button, and the pin will redirect back to the vimeo site, but I would like for users to be able to play the video within Pinterest.

Here is my code:

```
    <iframe src='http://player.vimeo.com/video/79431683' height='200' width='300' title='0' frameborder='0'></iframe>
    <a target="_blank"  style="width: 250px" href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http://www.vimeo.com/79431683&media=http%3A%2F%2Fb.vimeocdn.com%2Fts%2F455%2F119%2F455119255_640.jpg&description=JeremyAndLoni" class='pin-it-button' data-pin-config='above'><img src='//assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pinit_fg_en_rect_red_28.png'/></a>
```

You can also see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/5n2N8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will be helpful:
you can use this plugin [addthis](https://www.addthis.com/)
and use this code:

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style" addthis:url="URL TO VIMEO VIDEO">
   <a class="addthis_button_pinterest_pinit"></a>
</div>
```